# creating a input file for weighted graph in c++

Tags: file, input, data-structures, graph, weighted

- How to create a input file for weighted graph?
- Suppose there are 10 cities and there are distances between each cities are weighted.
  example:
- seattle->San Francisco = 1306
- seattle->Denver = 2161
- Denver->Dallas = 1050
- Denver->Minneapolis = 1483
  .
  .
  .
  so on

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with "how to create"? You can to write a program which prints an input-file? Or you want to know how to format an input file for a weighted graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input file for your graph could look something like this, storing number of edges in first line and edges in all additional lines:

```
10
Seattle, San Francisco, 1306
Seattle, Denver, 2161
Denver, Dallas, 1050
Denver, Minneapolis, 1483
...
```

The tricky part is however parsing that information and storing it.

You can also store input as adjacency list like. See below.

```
Seattle: (San Francisco, 1306), (Denver, 2161)
Denver: (Dallas, 1050), (Minneapolis, 1483)
...
```

You have several options, but at the end you will need to parse text file you read into some other form (adjacency matrix, adjacency list, ...) no matter what the input is.